# Flutter : Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<double>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting following error:

> E/flutter (21169): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)]
> Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type
> 'List' in type cast

type of getPatientDataList() is `Future<List<List<dynamic>> Function()`.

and I want to create a `List<List<<double>>>` i.e. sublist.            But all time failed.

```
  getPatientDataList().then((result) {
  dataSize = result.length;

  List<List<double>> list = (result.getRange(0, 500).toList()).cast<List<List<double>>>();
  print("data " + list.toString());
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to create new list from 0 to 500 ? and what is `result`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yeah, I want to  create new list. and this list have to be List<List<double>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a task from the school course.

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  getPatientDataList().then((result) {
    final dataSize = result.length;
    final List<List<double>> list = result
        .getRange(1, 3)
        .map((e) => e.map((e) => e as double).toList())
        .toList();
    print("data " + list.toString());
  });
}

Future<List<List>> getPatientDataList() async {
  return <List<dynamic>>[
    [0.0, 0.5],
    [1.0, 1.5],
    [2.0, 2.5],
    [3.0, 3.5],
  ];
}
```

Output:

```
data [[1.0, 1.5], [2.0, 2.5]]
```

Or even...

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  getPatientDataList().then((result) {
    final dataSize = result.length;
    final List<List<double>> list =
        result.getRange(1, 3).map((e) => e.cast<double>()).toList();
    print("data " + list.toString());
  });
}
```

And so...

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  getPatientDataList().then((result) {
    final dataSize = result.length;
    final List<List<double>> list =
        List.of(result.getRange(1, 3).map((e) => e.cast()));   
    print("data " + list.toString());
  });
}
```

Comment: Finally , thank you so muchhh

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
getPatientDataList().then((result) {
  dataSize = result.length;

  List<dynamic> list = (result.getRange(0, 500).toList()).cast<List<double>();
  print("data " + list.toString());

});
```

Comment: Unfortunetly, again failed. I have to cast this  list  as  List<List<double>>();